# jquery datepicker links to own script url instead picking date google apps script

Tags: jquery, datepicker, google-apps-script

A problem I face using the jQuery datepicker:

In a Google Apps Script HTML template, the following happens:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.23/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

The datepicker presents itself like this:
http://i.imm.io/V2EH.png

When hovering a date, you see in the bottom that a link is generated. Selecting a date will cause the script to reload, instead of the date value to be entered in the field...

I am confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the forcing the script to reload, it's only the current page url appended with the "#". As each anchor tag inside in the datepicker dialog have the href="#" nothing else.
[image]